# Scrolling horizontally while having multiple listboxes arranged in vertical scrolling

Tags: canvas

please advice, i managed to bind all listbox to scroll vertically with vertical scrollbar, but cannot find reason why it don't scroll H

```
root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH) #.grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=500,height=500,scrollregion=(0,0,1500,1500))


def on_mouse_wheel(event):

    # automate Listbox creation
    for i in range(10):
        lb[i].yview("scroll", event.delta // 50, "units")
    return "break"
```

This generate listboxes, and get value while scrolling:

> ```
> data = read_from_database()
>
> x = 0
> for index, dat in enumerate(data):
>     x = len(dat)
> print(x)
> lb = {}
> for i in range(10):
>     listbox = Listbox(canvas, width=14, relief="sunken")
>     listbox.pack(side="left", fill="y", expand=False)
>     lb[i] = listbox
>     for index, dat in enumerate(data):
>         lb[i].insert(index, dat[i])
>         lb[i].bind("<MouseWheel>", on_mouse_wheel)
>
>
>
>
> def on_vsb(*args):
>
>     # # automate Listbox yview method creation
>     for i in range(10):
>         lb[i].yview(*args)
> ```

```
hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
vbar=Scrollbar(canvas,orient=VERTICAL, command=on_vsb)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
canvas.config(width=500,height=500)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: As I was thinking, it surely is because I cannot make proper command to scroll, using xview works only with text widget, using canvas scroll (after creating canvas inside frame) also don't scroll all listbox (I dont want to scroll data inside listbox, but all of them together because i have 20 of them), of course I can make rows more thin, but it still is a problem if I add more listboxes. Probably problem starts because I use pack method on each listbox